# How can I add duplicate rows to LibreOffice Calc to make there be one per day?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have some data like this (it's stock market data)

```
29/07/2015  35972.82    32056.2 17751.39
30/07/2015  35961.86    32046.43    17745.98
31/07/2015  35848.13    31945.08    17689.86
03/08/2015  35662.37    31779.55    17598.2
04/08/2015  35566.11    31693.77    17550.69
```

There is not one row per day because the data provider omits days in which the market is closed.

I need there to be one row per day, and rows should be duplicated where necessary to fill the gaps

```
29/07/2015  35972.82    32056.2 17751.39
30/07/2015  35961.86    32046.43    17745.98
31/07/2015  35848.13    31945.08    17689.86
01/08/2015  35848.13    31945.08    17689.86
02/08/2015  35848.13    31945.08    17689.86
03/08/2015  35662.37    31779.55    17598.2
04/08/2015  35566.11    31693.77    17550.69
```

Is there a way to do this in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the data at the top of a sheet named "Sheet1".  Create a new sheet named "Sheet2".

In cell A1 of Sheet2 enter the following formula.

```
=Sheet1.A1
```

In cell A2 of Sheet2 enter this formula and fill it down to A7.

```
=A1+1
```

For this to work correctly, the dates must be [date values](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Date_and_Time_Functions), not strings.  If the dates on Sheet1 are strings, convert them by going to *Data -> Text to Columns*.  Select the column and specify the date format.

Now in cell B1 of Sheet2 enter the following formula, fill down to B7 then over to D7.

```
=VLOOKUP($A1;$Sheet1.$A$1:$D$5;COLUMN())
```

This produces the desired result as shown in the question.

Documentation: [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP), [COLUMN](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#COLUMN).